# Why do I need list context when writing unix command output to a file in Perl?

Tags: perl, unix, cut

I'm trying to output the output from a unix command to a file handle (which goes to an output file). Initially my code was like this:

```
open (OUT,'>',$out)|| die "cannot open $out";
my $file =`cut -f $list $in`;
print OUT $file;
close OUT;
```

It gave me a "segmentation fault" error message, which is pretty rare for a perl script... I searched around and make one small change below in the second and third line by changing the output into an array `@file` instead of variable `$file` and somehow, for whatever reason, it worked!

```
open (OUT,'>',$out)|| die "cannot open $out";
my @file =`cut -f $list $in`;
print OUT @file;
close OUT;
```

Does anyone understand why it worked and what is the difference between outputting into array vs a scalar?

Comment: What was the real error message you got?

Comment: That is not the complete output.

Comment: Given the code fragment, why not use: `system "cut -f $list $in > $out";` so that Perl doesn't have to ingest the whole of the output from the command before writing it all out to the file anyway? How big was the file whose name is stored in `$in`. If it is gigabytes in size and you're using a 32-bit Perl, you could run into trouble simply because a 32-bit program only has a couple of GiB (less than 4 GiB) available for variable storage.

Comment: What is `$in`? Did you define that before, or did you have a constant there?  Can you add some `print` statements, so you can see which line was the issue? Did the program fail on the `my $file = `cut -f $line $in;`? or did if fail when attempting to print it out?

Comment: perl version?  what is $out?

Comment: segmentation fault was indeed the complete error message...

Comment: yeah, i didn't get it right to let system() output it to a file.. that's why I went to the ``, file handle route..

Comment: $in is the only input to the script. $out is my output file. perl version is v5.14.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qx`/`readpipe`/backticks in scalar context will try to load the external command's output into a single scalar variable. In list context, the output is loaded into a list of several scalars.

If the external command's output is extraordinarily long, Perl might choke on trying to cram it into a single string, but not have a problem creating several small strings and loading them to an array.

Comment: This might be the reason!! In this script, it indeed is handling a very long string (over several G).. i guess this is probably is it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I ran a quick test of your initial program:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
use strict;
use feature qw(say);
use warnings;

my $out = "test.out";
my $list = "2";
my $in = "test.txt";
open OUT,'>',$out || die "cannot open $out";
my $file =`cut -f $list $in`;
print OUT $file;
close OUT;
```

My test file looked like this:

```
this    that
who     knows
who     cares
I       know
```

My `test.out` file looks like this:

```
that
knows
cares
know
```

If the test file didn't exist, the program still runs, and I get an error printed out on STDERR by `cut`. If I give it a bad field spec, the program still runs and I get another error printed on STDERR by `cut`.

I've tried a few things, but couldn't get the program to fail outright with a segmentation fault.

So, the question is what is producing that segmentation fault. Is it `cut` or Perl? Put a print statement after the `my $file =`cut -f $list $in`;` and the `print OUT $file;` lines and see if they print anything. If they do, the problem is with `cut` and not with Perl. If not, somehow your Perl interpreter is having problems. So, then the question is why does it work on my system and not yours:

- What version of Perl are you using?
- What exactly is the OS? Is this Linux, Mac OSX, Cygwin running under Windows, or some old ancient version of Solaris/SunOS?
- Is this the entire message?
- Was any of your `$out` file written?

The program you wrote should work and does on my systems. I'm using Perl 5.14 on Mac OS X 10.9 and on Perl 5.8.8 on a Linux RHEL box. I haven't tried this on Cygwin.

Comment: I think mob's answer probably explained it. Thanks for your input though!

Comment: it's perl v5.14.2 on a linux sever and when I run it on a small test dataset, it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

I can't say why it worked, but the difference between calling the [backticks operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) in scalar and list context is:

- in list context, `qx//` will return a list of output lines split on `$/` ( the input record separator) but including those line endings
- in scalar context, it will just return a single string

Here is an example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dump;

my $foo = `perl -e "print qq{foo\nbar baz};"`;
my @bar = `perl -e "print qq{foo\nbar baz};"`;

dd $foo;
dd @bar;
```

Which produces

```
"foo\nbar baz"
("foo\n", "bar baz")
```

Comment: thanks! I got this now as also mentioned in mob's answer which I thought explained it